# Adding UIImageView Objects in UIView to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, uiview, nsmutablearray

I believe I may be dealing with some view issues which are not allowing me to detect and add `UIImageView` objects to an array.   I could really use some suggestions.

I've got a number of `UIImageViews` with images linked to a `UIView` that sits on top of a `UIViewController` (the `UIView` was added to help with `drawRect` and some additional advantages).  So, when I touch an image and 'drag and drop' it, I want to add that image to an array upon being dropped.

My `touchesBegan` gets the location of the touch and checks `UIImageView` is being touched and then centers on that view as follows:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

            UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];  //can't use self.view in a UIView, this may be causing issues?

            startLocation = location;  // for reference as needed



    NSLog(@"Image x coord:   %f", location.x);

    NSLog(@"Image y coord:   %f", location.y);

    if ([touch view] == obiWan_Block)

            {obiWan_Block.center = location;}

    else if ([touch view] == r2d2_Block)

            {r2d2_Block.center = location;}

    else if ([touch view] == you_Block)

            {you_Block.center = location;}

}
```

Then, I drag the `UIImageView` around with `touchesMoved` and finally, 'drop' the image with `touchesEnded`.  When the `UIImageView` is drop in a certain area of the screen, I 'snap' it to a specific location.  It's at this point I want to place this `UIImageView` into an array, but I'm having no luck.  I believe I'm getting confused on the various views being touched and what's getting added via `addObject` to my `NSMutableArray`.  Or, I could be missing something completely.  Here's my `touchedEnded` method:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

          UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

          CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];

          UIView *temp = [touch view];

          UIImageView *currentImageView = (UIImageView *)[touch view];  //DON'T THINK THIS IS RIGHT

    NSLog(@"Current Image View is:   %@", currentImageView);

    if ((location.x > dropZone.origin.x) && (location.y >= dropZone.origin.y) && ([touch view] != NULL))

        {

            CGRect frame = temp.frame;

            if (touchCount == 0) {

                frame.origin.x = 15;

                frame.origin.y = 180;

                temp.frame = frame;

                [quoteArray addObject: currentImageView];

                touchCount++;

                }

            else if (touchCount == 1) {

                frame.origin.x = 70;

                frame.origin.y = 180;

                temp.frame = frame;

                [quoteArray addObject: currentImageView]; 

                touchCount++;

                }

                ....
```

I have an `NSLog` statement to check if `addObject` is working as follows:

```
NSLog(@"the quote array contains %d items. Contents = %@",[quoteArray count], quoteArray);
```

The log always says:

> the quote array contains 0 items. Contents = (null)

Please advise and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last part of code shows that you have uninitialized `quoteArray`. Check code when you create it, I guess you missed something in your init method. Because if array was correct then NSLog should show below:

```
NSArray *quoteArray = [NSArray array];
NSLog(@"%@", quoteArray);
```

> 2011-11-17 17:37:00.506 TestApp[1382:207] ( )

Comment: Thanks!!  I was indeed initializing my `NSMutableArray` in the wrong place.  It's always the simple things that take hours to fix!  :-)